# DummyMemcachedBackupSessionManager constantly throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, session, tomcat, tomcat7, memcached

I'm trying to implement non-sticky Tomcat session sharing with [memcached-session-manager](https://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/) version 1.6.3. In my desktop development environment, I want to use `de.javakaffee.web.msm.DummyMemcachedBackupSessionManager` as the manager class because I don't have a memcached fleet set up in dev.

The problem I am running into is that `DummyMemcachedBackupSessionManager` seems to be crudely implemented in the sense that it causes a `NullPointerException` every time there's an attempt to load the session. My log is filled with stack traces like this one:

```
May 06, 2015 5:24:59 PM de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedSessionService loadFromMemcached
WARNING: Could not load session with id 0D66BAE28A0B302425186CD6B3F62DAA-n1 from memcached.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedSessionService.loadFromMemcached(MemcachedSessionService.java:1111)
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedSessionService.findSession(MemcachedSessionService.java:597)
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.DummyMemcachedSessionService.findSession(DummyMemcachedSessionService.java:113)
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager.findSession(MemcachedBackupSessionManager.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2981)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2378)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:897)
        at com.amazon.sentry.TomcatSSOFilter.setSessionAttributes(TomcatSSOFilter.java:133)
...
```

Is there some configuration I can do using version 1.6.3 to avoid polluting my logs with all of these NPEs?

For reference, my `context.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<Context>
    <Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.DummyMemcachedBackupSessionManager"
             sticky="false"
             lockingMode="none"
             sessionBackupAsync="false"
             memcachedNodes="n1:dummy-node:0"
             requestUriIgnorePattern="\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
    />
</Context>
```